# How do I round only floating digit in PHP?

Tags: php, rounding

I have a php output 14.85, i want to make it 14.90 for 14.50 and for 14.47. I am trying with round function but i am not getting right number format,  Is it possible ?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

`number_format(round($var, 1), 2)` should do the trick.

Comment: I tried with round(14.47, 1); it is showing 14.5, Is it possible to show 14.50 instead of 14.5 ? thanks

Comment: @ShamimAhmed sure, just use `number_format`. I've edited my answer to include it.

Comment: I tried with echo number_format(round(4.47, 2), 2) it is showing 4.47 instead of 4.50

Answer (score 0):

As in most of programming languages you can use `ceil()`, `floor()` or `round()`